# remove (or rename) gradle java sourceSet

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, java-platform-module-system

I'd like to rename the default gradle java sourceSet `main`. As far as I know, this isn't directly possible, but I though I should be able to create a new sourceSet and delete `main`, as in:

```
sourceSets {remove main}

sourceSets {
    'foo.bar' {
        java {
            srcDir "src/$name/java"
        }
        resources {
            srcDir "src/$name/resources"
        }
        output.classesDir "$buildDir/classes/$name"
        output.resourcesDir "$buildDir/classes/$name"

    }
}
```

This runs without errors, but gradle still compiles everything in `src/main/java`, and ignores anything in `src/foo.bar/java`. What am I doing wrong?

(In case anyone wonders why the strange name `foo.bar`: I'm experimenting with JDK 1.9 "Jigsaw", and the new Java modules require directory names with dots.)

Comment: Though this is old, but did you not have a module-info in the project mentioned in the question?

Comment: No, I didn’t, but both Java 9 and Gradle have moved on since I asked the question. I’m still waiting for full module support in Gradle (only libraries supported for now). My question is, however, moot by now.

Comment: Why do you call your question moot? It is not? We need one source set for each module, and so the desire to rename `main` is tremendous lol.